# How does one pass html to page in View through ViewData in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

Okay, so maybe this is a no no in the MVC pattern in which case, that's the answer I'm looking for. However, let's say I have some content html in a database and I want to pass it through to the view. I am assuming I could use a ViewData property to pass this through to the page. What sort of massaging do I need to do to the string to get something like `<h1>Hello World</h1>` to show up as '**Hello World**' instead of '<h1>Hello World</h1>'.

Comment: Note that using ViewData for stuff like this isn't a "no no", per se, but I think that strongly typing your view and/or using the MVVM pattern is a little better long-term strategy and less typo/error prone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing, just do `<%=ViewData["yourkey"] %>` instead of `<%=Html.Encode(ViewData["yourkey"]) %>` in your view.

**Note:** Only do this if you are absolutely sure you trust the data in the database!

Comment: That's great...you mean looking at the code might actually help? But seriously, thanks for pointing out the obvious in a way that didn't make me feel stupid.

Answer (score -1):

You'd need to strip out the HTML before you put the string into the ViewData.

EDIT: When you print the ViewData directly to the page, it shouldn't escape the HTML markup.

```
<%=ViewData["whatever"]%>
```

That's C#, but it's very similar in VB.NET.

Comment: I want the html in the string to be interpreted as html when it gets to the page.